# string comparison failure for xml string comparison

Tags: java

I am working on a Junit test where the output of a method is a String in XML format.I am not sure why the string comparison is failing

```
Assert.assertEquals("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>\n" +
            "<RATE>1.0</RATE>", XMLUtil.formatXML(TEST_XML));


Actaul response from the method :
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<RATE>1.0</RATE>
```

Error :

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: expected:<...oding="ISO-8859-1"?>[
<RATE>1.0</RATE>]> but was:<...oding="ISO-8859-1"?>[
<RATE>1.0</RATE>
]>
    ]
```

**EDIT**
Even adding new line in the end doesnt help:

```
Assert.assertEquals("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>\n" +
                "<RATE>1.0</RATE>\n", XMLUtil.formatXML(TEST_XML));

junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: expected:<...oding="ISO-8859-1"?>[
<RATE>1.0</RATE>]
> but was:<...oding="ISO-8859-1"?>[
<RATE>1.0</RATE>
]
>
```

Comment: Different or missing line ending would be an obvious possibility

Comment: The _actual_ response has a new line at the end of the XML. Side note: this looks like it would be somehwat unreliable.

Comment: how can i create a string with the correct line ending ?

Comment: use trim() to remove the line endings

Comment: @RNJ even trim is not helping

Comment: It seems like an encoding problem. Have you edited the source file with several editors? or copy-and-paste the line from other source? Try to type again the string in the test and in the XMLUtil.formatXML method.

Comment: Consider using [XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/) for the job. Many things (not just line-spacing) may differ in XML while still making two files similar. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected and actual XML may have different carriage control character content. Try removing all newline and linefeed characters

```
String expected = 
       "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>RATE>1.0</RATE>";
Assert.assertEquals(expected,
       "<RATE>1.0</RATE>", XMLUtil.formatXML(TEST_XML).replaceAll("[\r\n]", "");
```

Comment: i'd remove tabs too. actually i'd consider removing all whitespace ie `\\s`

Comment: That depends. The test may need to test for exact whitespace content.